# C# Generic type event args

Tags: c#, silverlight, events

Here is my class definition for a customized event args

```
using System;

public class DeserializeEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public DeserializeEventArgs(T deserializeResult)
    {
        this.DeserializeResult = deserializeResult;
    }

    public T DeserializeResult
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

And I want to do this in the code where I want to fire this event

```
public event EventHandler<DeserializeEventArgs<T>> DeserializeEvent;
```

And it will not compile (red line under T says no type found). Not sure if this is the right way of using it, anyone has experience please share some idea.

Thank you

Comment: I believe when you declare your event, you need to give it a type to use, just like you are doing with the EventHandler<T>

Comment: As Stefan said, something like `public event EventHandler<DeserializedEventArgs<int>> DeserializeEvent;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe when you declare your event, you need to give it a type to use, just like you are doing with the EventHandler

```
public event EventHandler<DeserializeEventArgs<T>> DeserializeEvent;
```

needs to be

```
public event EventHandler<DeserializeEventArgs<YourType>> DeserializeEvent;
```

Answer (score 2):

`T` is a type parameter - essentially a stand-in for the actual type you're going to use. Whatever type of object you wanted passed with your `Deserialize` event, you should instead put its name there.

If your class is called "Data" then:

```
public event EventHandler<DeserializeEventArgs<Data>> DeserializeEvent;
```